# Js field manipulation in inline modal

Tags: laravel-backpack

It is possible to manipulate fields in inline create modal with Javascript?

I have several inline create fields like that

```
CRUD::addField([
            'type' => "relationship",
            'name' => 'authors', 
            'ajax' => true,
            'attribute' => 'fullName',
            'inline_create' => [
                'entity' => 'author',
                ] 
        ]);
```

I tried using crud.field('authors').subfield('name') but doesn'r work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the script widget with `->inline()`.

For example:

```php
Widget::add()->type('script')->content('assets/js/products/inline-fields.js')->inline();
```

Note that you need to add this script in the `setupCreateOperation` of the related crud you create inside the modal.

Cheers

Comment: Great! I didn't saw that on the docs. Works perfectly as usual